# How to calculate the standard deviation of a variable

Tags: standard-deviation

I have determined the slope of a linear fit and its standard deviation. Now I need to calculate k, which is 1/slope, but I don’t know to calculate the standard deviation of k. Is it 1/standard deviation of slope? If not, can someone, please, shine some light?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Note that if you reversed the regression, you would not get the reciprocal of the original slope.  If the density of the distribution of the slope estimate is positive for a zero slope, then the expectation of the reciprocal of the slope will be undefined and there will be no standard deviation.

Comment: Doing that will determine a dissociation constant which is the value that I need to use; also I am asked for standard deviation as well